# echo a string when getting a "Permission denied" in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am writing a simple bash script to download files from a remote folder, but it has to be executed as root.

```
echo "message1"

scp location1:file location2

echo "message1"

chmod a+r file1

echo "All done"
```

I am sure it will **not** be executed as root on the first time and it would be useful to prompt the user to do it. Is there any way to show a message after it prints "permission denied"? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the top of the script

```
((EUID == 0)) || { echo 'Run as root' >&2; exit 1; }
```

`EUID` is always `0` when running with root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1 (not recommended)

Inspired from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/746351/356625).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$UID" -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Permission denied."
    exec sudo "$0" "$@"
else
    echo "Permission granted."
fi
```

Run:

```
./solution1.sh
Permission denied.
[sudo] password for imampt:
Permission granted.
```

The problem is, when you run it again:

```
./solution1.sh
Permission denied.
Permission granted.
```

This is because the credential is cached.

### Solution 2 (recommended)

Inspired from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/900955/356625).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if ! sudo -n true 2> /dev/null;
then
    echo "Permission denied."
    exec sudo "$0" "$@"
else
    echo "Permission granted."
fi
```

When the credential is cached, it will print "Permission granted" right away.

Comment: [Check exit code directly](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2181), and you could also just do `#!/usr/bin/sudo bash`

Comment: @Nobody Thanks for the suggestion . I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you *could* achieve similar results by simply declaring that a password isn't needed when calling `sudo` for (a) specific user(s), group(s), and/or command(s) by editing the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Here is a good tutorial:
https://linuxhandbook.com/sudo-without-password/

as well as an explanation of the differences of executing commands with `sudo` vs as `root`: https://superuser.com/a/771523